# Customized django all-auth form not submitting

Tags: django, form-submit, django-allauth, django-custom-field

I am using the django all-auth login form. I wanted to customize the look of the form fields so I changed login.html within the account folder to look like this:

```
<form class="login" method="POST" action="{% url 'account_login' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form.visible_fields|slice:'2' %}
        <div class="row form-group">
            {% if field.name == 'login' %}
                <input type="text" placeholder="Email"><i class="fas fa-at"></i>
            {% else %}
                <input type="password" placeholder="Password"><i class="la la-lock"></i>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <a href="{% url 'account_reset_password' %}">Forgot Password?</a>
    <button type="submit">Sign In</button>
</form>
```

The form renders exactly how I would like it to, however nothing happens when I click on submit. What is strange to me is that the form submits perfectly fine if in place of my for loop I simply type `{{ form.as_p }}`, it just doesn't look how I want. Can anyone see an error in my loop, or is there something else wrong here. I have been looking for a solution online but so far been unsuccessful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the names of the fields in your input tags otherwise the POST dictionary will be empty. You are using `{% if field.name == 'login' %}` but you forgot to specify the name attribute. Same applies for the password input.

```
<form class="login" method="POST" action="{% url 'account_login' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form.visible_fields|slice:'2' %}
        <div class="row form-group">
            {% if field.name == 'login' %}
                <input name='login' type="text" placeholder="Email"><i class="fas fa-at"></i>
            {% else %}
                <input name='password' type="password" placeholder="Password"><i class="la la-lock"></i>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <a href="{% url 'account_reset_password' %}">Forgot Password?</a>
    <button type="submit">Sign In</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Yep that did it. Thanks a lot